# Ошибка: "Приложение не установлено" после неудачной установки GridTab

Tags: java, android, ide

После неудачной установки GridTab (проблемы с электросетью) на Android Studio я теперь не могу установить ни одну программу на смартфон. Они компилируются без ошибок, всё вроде бы хорошо, но установка программы на смартфон всё время прерывается сообщением "Приложение не установлено". В чём может быть дело?

Comment: Он был же подсоединен к АS? Может сброс поможет? В крайнем случае перепрошейте смарт. Это очень легко делается, инструкции можно найти на 4pda. В гугле вводите "прошивка модель_смарта 4pda".

Answer (score 1):

Установите любой эмулятор андроида, например:

- NOX
- MEMU

и попробуйте в него устанавливать, этим вы исключите проблему со смартом.

Если не поможет, то вам делать сброс настроек на дефолт (можете предварительно забекапить свои), и последнее , переустановка самой IDE и повторная установка компонентов и плагинов.